# Can Windows group policy in an enterprise environment change without user intervention, such as a windows update?

Tags: windows-10, updates, group-policy

Greetings my fellow nerds, I have never heard of microsoft updates cause group policy changes. So I began to wonder is there a way that GPO can be altered without user intervention. From what I know its not possible but I can be wrong.

I was wondering if someone knowledgeable in Windows Systems could chime in and provide a bit of context. I appreciate any feedback in advance, thank you!

Comment: What? The entire point of GP is that computers can be fully managed, largely without user interaction. What is your actual question? What research have you done? What are you trying to accomplish or is this just a theoretical problem?

Comment: Yes I were my question could lead to some confusion my apologies. By user I meant admins in general not necessarily the people using the hosts. From my understanding a windows update can not alter the policies set.

Something occurred that broke our environment desktop locked down, missing files and icons. It was later fixed by disabling gpo's and applying new ones. Still I appreciate your feedback, thank you.

Comment: Windows Updates may change the default value for a Group Policy setting. If you've manually set a value for a given GP, that would not be overwritten, but if you'd left defaults, those MAY change in certain cases, but these will be exceptionally rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, after all microsoft updates are applied to individual machines, not the domain as a whole, so it wouldn't make sense for an update on one AD server to alter the policy applied to all of them.

Since the standard is to have multiple AD servers, it would also potentially cause major issues, since some machines receiving the policy would know about what the new policy means and others wouldn't.

That said, I think updates CAN change the result / or how the machine behaves when processing a policy. For instance if Microsoft deprecated a particular policy item, that item would still be listed in the policy but the client might no longer process it in the same way once it has been updated, or may ignore it entirely.

You can see the result of that sometimes in domains that have been running for a while, where you might have policies configured for settings within Windows XP or 7, even though you've long since retired/upgraded all those machines to newer versions. The policy object and its settings are still there, and the client may well still receive them, but they no longer have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

In an enterprise domain, the domain administrator is all-powerful and
can change any group policy from his login, being as precise as he
wants in choosing the population to which this change will apply.

In most cases, the change will happen when the concerned users log on.

So, yes, group policies can change, and not only because of Windows Update.